# Exact sequence in $D(\mathcal{A})$?

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra, exact-sequence, derived-categories

I am currently reading some notes on homological algebra, more specifically derived categories. After introducing (distinguished) triangles of complexes the author states the following theorem:

[image]

Now this is a little bit confusing to me as to what he means by an exact sequenec in $D(\mathcal{A})$. I would assume that $u$, $v$ and $w$ are morphisms in the category of chain complexes, because otherwise I don't know how the homology morphisms are given. When he says exact in $D(\mathcal{A})$, does he mean distinguished?

The proof of the theorem is then given:

[image]

As I don't understand what the assumptions of the theorem are I have trouble understanding why the first sequence in the proof is quasi isomorphic to (III.19).

Comment: I presume he means distinguished triangle when he says exact sequence. After all, distinguished triangles are the analogues in triangulated categories of exact sequences in Abelian categories. I presume he has also proved a lemma on the quasi-isomorphism of these two distinguished triangles.